# What's going on with the Ropsten network

Tags: ropsten

What is going on with the Ropseten testnet? The last block(7752138) was mined at 07:24:17 AM +UTC which was, at the time of writing this, 23minutes ago.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/7752138

Answer (score 2):

Ropsten network looks normal now after some delay now mining is restarted